# Passing a list item in a Less variable to check the guards at single call

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to pass a list item in a Less variable to check the guard option? I have a set of rules which have guard condition to retrieve the CSS. Please refer the below sample code.

**demo.less:**

```
@obj = none;

& when (@obj = tree), (@obj = none){
   .tree{
         color: green;
   }
}
& when (@obj = wood), (@obj = none){
   .wood{
         color: brown;
   }
}

.......
```

I have a big list of rules like above code, so it takes more time to compile the less to CSS for each variable to call by the `less.render` function.

Is there a way to retrieve all CSS rules by call at a single time?

**demo.js:**

```
less.render(lessData, { modifyVars: { obj: "tree"} }, function (err, output) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            -----
            -----
        }
    });
```

I would like to call something like **modifyVars: { obj: ["tree","wood",...] }** to get all CSS rules.

Comment: Hmm, I can imagine a few methods though  first of all I wonder why do you need such conditional compilation for *every single* ruleset at all? (this is really weird to say at least). At quick glance, since your CSS code generation de facto sits in JS anyway, the easiest way would be generate a string with those rulesets directly in JS (and then append the generated string to either your Less or CSS). This way you at least won't need to repeat `wood` three times in your code for the corresponding ruleset to appear in the output (that's what asks if Less is necessary in this case at all).

Comment: Regardless of above, notice your guards code can be simplified to be [twice less verbose](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/9ff49c0ff6be1daeebd2).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked your suggestion but I cant use it. In my real application it has various classes inside each rules not only the same class. Actually my requirement is (1.) To get all the CSS at initial, so I have set a default variable @obj=none; (2.) To pass some variable in the less to retrieve the corresponding CSS based on the ruleset. I can get the less codes as string in JS and parse it using less.render. But it takes much time to parse css for each modifyVars. Sorry I couldn't get your comments. Can you please describe with detailed description?

Comment: "To pass some variable in the less to retrieve the corresponding CSS based on the ruleset." - then a more proper method (or at least a direction to look at)  would probably be would be to have those things in different files to pass to `less.render` independently (instead of having a dump of everything in a single file with conditional retrieval like you trying to make it). That's why I'm actually asking of "why" - it definitely smells like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/243609).